# Appositives with possessiveness?

Tags: possessives, appositives

I would like to say something like

> The boy, Adam's, favorite toy was a bike.

What is the proper way to say this?

Comment: I had the same question. I don't like `boy's`.  In the end I rewrote it to avoid the mess. Something like `The favorite toy of the boy, Adam, was a bike.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. That's right.

The possessive ***-'s*** suffix has gone from being a paradigmatic [Genitive Case](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsGenitiveCase.htm) suffix that marks the possessor noun in Old English (or [Modern German](http://german.about.com/library/blcase_gen.htm)), to being a syntactic [clitic marker](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsACliticGrammar.htm) in Modern English that marks the end of a Noun Phrase containing the possessor (e.g, *the King of England's mistress*).

Since *the boy* and *Adam* are both noun phrases in an apposition relation, that in itself constitutes an NP, and that NP ends with *Adam*. Hence that's where ***-'s*** may be placed.

> *The boy, Adam's, favorite toy was a bike.*

However, ***-'s*** may also mark **both** of the apposed NPs, since they're NPs too, and they're both possessors.

> *The boy's, Adam's, favorite toy was a bike.*

In writing, this last construction might be a good occasion to use a dash to set off the appositive.

> *The boy's – Adam's – favorite toy was a bike.*

Comment: Thanks so much! To be honest, the second sentence you provided was what I figured would be correct, though it sounded quite weird, so I was going to stick with what I had. The last sentence, however, sounds and looks perfectly fine and grammatically correct.

Comment: [Punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) is always a crapshoot. Sister Mary Nazarita never discussed dashes -- feeling perhaps that they were beneath her august notice -- so I had to figure out their intonation curve myself.

Comment: Maybe ok in speech, sure.  All speech is okay. But beyond that, I disagree. Not sure I accept that kind of appositive in most writing. The King of England's mistress is fine.

Comment: There is no language beyond speech. Spoken language is real language; writing is just modern technology. English could be written in Chinese characters and it'd still be English.

Comment: Imho, this *particular* example could reasonably be articulated *with or without* a pause between the generic noun ***boy*** and (particularizing, "appositive") ***Adam***. Same as the optional commas/pauses setting off the specific name in, say, *That's my uncle, John, over there*. But regardless of whether they're separated by a pause or not, the two terms collectively effectively constitute a "composite noun" (***boy + Adam*** and ***uncle + John***) subordinate to the clitic **'s**. And to my mind, valid orthography includes *parenthesizing* the second term in the pair.