# What is correct? "My cat's, Tiger's, food is on sale." "My cat's, Tiger, food is on sale."

Tags: possessives

What is correct?

My cat's, Tiger's, food is on sale.

My cat, Tiger's, food is on sale.

My cat's, Tiger, food is on sale.

Comment: If you must try to cram too much information into one sentence, put the _-'s_ after _Tiger_ and remove all the commas.

Comment: Sorry, @JohnLawler, that's too simple and clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appositives with possessiveness?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57700/appositives-with-possessiveness) '_The boy, Adam's, favorite toy was a bike._'? ...  'Since the boy and Adam are both noun phrases in an apposition relation, that in itself constitutes an NP, and that NP ends with Adam. Hence that's where -'s may be placed.

_The boy, Adam's, favorite toy was a bike._' (John Lawler)

Comment: Questions about correctness are usually better handled over at [ell.se]

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming Tiger is the name of your cat and his food is on sale - if that's really what you want to convey, it should read: *My cat Tiger's food is on sale.* (Possessive before noun)

Comment: No comma between NPs in an appositive relation? Have you a supporting reference, T-E-T? If you check, you will find that unsupported answers are rarely considered convincing on ELU.